# Why my compute field does not work on the reverse side?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have the computed field `x_totalunity` which depends on the fields `product_uom_qty` and `x_unitparcarton`.

What I want is to be able to write also any value in `x_totalunity` and that `product_uom_qty` changes due to this (`product_uom_qty = x_totalunity / x_unitparcarton`). But this does not work.

This is my code :

```
@api.depends('product_uom_qty', 'discount', 'price_unit', 'tax_id',
             'x_unitparcarton'  )
def _compute_amount(self):
"""
compute the amounts of the SO line.
"""
for line in self:
    line.x_totalunity = line.product_uom_qty * line.x_unitparcarton

x_totalunity = fields.Float(compute='_compute_amount', string='Total unitéé',
    readonly=False, store=True ,  required=True, copy=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove `discount`, `price_unit` and `tax_id` from the `@api.depends`, as they seem to have no relevance in the computation of `x_totalunity`.

Then, I think you are looking for the parameter `inverse`, to perform some actions in case someone is modifying the computed field by hand:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('product_uom_qty', 'x_unitparcarton')
def _compute_x_totalunity(self):
    """Compute the amounts of the SO line."""
    for line in self:
        line.x_totalunity = line.product_uom_qty * line.x_unitparcarton

@api.multi
def _inverse_x_totalunity(self):
    for line in self:
        line.product_uom_qty = line.x_totalunity / line.x_unitparcarton

x_totalunity = fields.Float(
    compute='_compute_x_totalunity',
    inverse='_inverse_x_totalunity',
    string='Total unitéé',
    required=True,
    readonly=False,
    store=True,
    copy=True,
)
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much .. there is just one problem , i have to click save so the changes happen to the  price it does not changes automatically , Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: May be you want to create other method with the decorator `@api.onchange('x_totalunity')`, to update the field `product_uom_qty` on the client side?

Comment: Thanks i'll try that

Comment: Could you help me with that ? I tried some things but i think i'm off a little bit